# How do you compare a string to a vector value?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

How to you do a string comparison in a to a value in a vector<std::string>?

I tried str, the error is printed below.

.....

```
    vector<std::string> dat;
    vector<std::string> pdat;
    dat = my();
    for(int b = 2; b < dat.size(); b+=7){
    //      cout << dat[b] << " " << endl;
            if(!strcmp(dat[b], "String\n"){    // The error is here
                    pdat.push_back(dat[b]);
            }
    }
```

my.cpp: In function 'std::vector > ngr()': 
my.cpp:53:32: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is compared with plain `==`. This works because the `==` operator is overloaded to do a string comparison for `std::string`s.

```
if (dat[b] == "String\n") {
```

If you're dealing with C++ strings, you shouldn't need any of the str* functions from string.h, so you might as well not include it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `operator==` on to compare an `std::string` and a `const char*` :

```
if(dat[b] == "String\n"){    //
    pdat.push_back(dat[b]);
}
```

For the record, the exact overload used here is the function template :

```
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, const CharT* rhs );
```

---

`strcmp` (that you dont need here, and rarely need in C++) expects `const char*` arguments :

```
int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );
```

So you could (but shouldn't) invoke it with th help of the `c_str()` member function :

```
if(!strcmp(dat[b].c_str(), "String\n") 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` expects 2 `const char*`s but `dat[b]` is a `string`, so you aren't comparing apples with apples.

You can either do

`if(!strcmp(dat[b].c_str(), "String\n"){`

Or

`if (dat[b] == "String\n") {`

The second is the more C++ approach.